# interpreting coefficient of Poisson regression, when dependent variable is a count variable

Tags: poisson-regression

I have a question about the economic interpretation of **Poisson regression**.

What is the economic interpretation of the coefficient when the dependent variable is a **count variable**?

For example, for "`Patent Count = a + b × R&D investment + c`", what does 1-unit increase in R&D investment mean for Patnet Count?

I know that when the dependent variable is log(Patent Count), a 1-unit increase in R&D investment, then the predicted Patent Count is multiplied by e^b, holding all other variables constant.

However, after reading all similar questions, I am still confused about what is an economic interpretation of the coefficient if the dependent variable is a count variable.

for Stata code `poisson Patent_count R&D_investment` , what is the economic interpretation of b?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In Poisson regression the left hand side is log(Patnet) not Patnet. Does that help?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+poisson+regression